# Визначення центру питального речення

Tags: синтаксис

*Я працюю над курсовою роботою в якій маю створити чатбота.*

Мене цікавить чи є якийсь універсальний (або майже універсальний) спосіб визначити центр питального реченння, а також чи можна розробити щось схоже на шаблон питального речення?

**За порадою [@bytebuster](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster) доповнення до питання:**

Для побудови чатбота я вирішив використати [Ланцюги Маркова](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B8_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0).

До цього часу мені вдалося розробити генератор випадкових фраз для якого потрібен початковий текст (я використовував Кайдашеву сім'ю, Чорну раду, П'ятнадцятирічний капітан та деякі інші твори).

***Пояснення роботи:***

Нехай у нас є початкові речення: *Чорний кіт любить червоні квіти* та *Білий кіт любить сині квіти*. Тоді ми можемо розбити кожне з цих речень на елементи певного розміру, для прикладу візьмемо розмір 2 слова, та співставити цьому елементу наступне слово що йде по порядку.

```
"Чорний кіт" -> "любить" : 1,  
"кіт любить" -> "червоні" : 1,
"любить червоні" -> "квіти" : 1,
```

Числами в слові що спіставляється є кількість варіантів які бувають після цього елемента.

В результаті з двома реченнями ця модель буде мати вигляд:

```
"Чорний кіт" -> ["любить" : 1],
"Білий кіт" -> ["любить" : 1],
"кіт любить" -> ["червоні" : 1, "сині": 1"], 
"любить червоні" -> ["квіти" : 1],
"любить сині" -> ["квіти" : 1],
"червоні квіти" -> [<кінець>: 1],
"сині квіти" -> [<кінець>: 1]
```

Таким чином можна отримати нові речення: *Білий кіт любить червоні квіти*

```
Початок: Білий кіт -> вибираємо випадково з варіантів "Білий кіт" ["любить" : 1],

Білий кіт любить ->  вибираємо випадково з варіантів "кіт любить" ["червоні" : 1, "сині": 1"]

Білий кіт любить червоні -> вибираємо випадково з варіантів "любить червоні" і т.д
```

Результати примітивні так як в роботі не враховуються мовні аспекти (крім вибору початку).

***Результат роботи:***

> Лаврінові дуже хотілось одкраяти свою частку від прибутків лаконі-
>   докинув работорговець.
>
> Саме тепер усі як ти мене водиш наче дитину.
>
> Буде й того що ти гуляєш у великому масштабі по всій скатерті.
>
> Одчини бо вікна поб'ю!
>
> Покажи мені хату твого батька.

*Більше про технічні деталі [тут](https://hackernoon.com/from-what-is-a-markov-model-to-here-is-how-markov-models-work-1ac5f4629b71#.3wu087d82) та дещо попередня версія моєї програми [тут](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185801/nodejs-random-sentence-generator-using-markov-chain) (я багато чого змінив з часу коли питання на Code Review було задане).*

Нажаль надто багато інформації про побудову чатботів на цьому принципі немає, але якщо б могти розбити кожну репліку співрозмовника (для початку саме питальні речення) на якісь елементарні об'єкти то можна б було співставляти з відповідями і можливо отримувати гарні результати.

### 02/02/18 Нові данні

Робота зрушила з місця після того як я знайшов проект [MegaHAL](https://megahal.alioth.debian.org/How.html). Найімовірніше суть питання вже не актуальна. Та якщо ком'юніті зацікавлене в роботі то я можу продовжувати доповнювати питання.

Comment: Дайте визначення "центру питального речення". Якщо в українській мові є якісь норми, що до розташування "центру" спільнота допоможе.  Зараз це питання з програмування, а не з галузді української мови.

Comment: Як на мене питання занадто [загальне](https://pidruchniki.com/1880041340571/dokumentoznavstvo/tipi_rechen). Спільнота не зможе дати однозначної відповіді. Голосую за закриття цього питання.